# How to remove [' '] from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, strip

New guy here, I am currently writing a web scraper for an exercise and I have encountered a problem with extracting the url to re-use. Basically I managed to get the URL but when I print it, it is still showing the `[' ']` (for example: `['http://123.com']` so it cannot be used as an input.

I am extracting the string using re.findall but then I tried to use .strip and .replace but it's I'm either getting a traceback or the input remains the same. Any suggestions please?

Extract:

```
z = re.findall(r'(?=htt).*?(?<=htm)', y)
h = str(z)
h = h.strip('\['"')
print(h)
```

Comment: `['http://123.com']`—That's a string inside a list. The string itself does not contain the brackets or quotes.

Comment: `z` is returning a list; if u just want the first element access by `z[0]`

Comment: Note that the entire purpose of ``re.findall`` is to find *several* matches. If you want only one matched string, use ``re.search`` or ``re.match``.

Answer (score 1):

re.findall returns a list.  Lists don't have strip or replace methods.  Access the element of the list by using z[0].  You could also use re.search if you're only looking for one string.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the answers in the comments, you can simply iterate over the list to access the elements inside like so:

```
for i in z:
    print(i)
```

You can substitute other methods instead of the print statement.

Comment: Hello, I actually found a method, I do not know if it is the correct one but it works:

    y = str(tag)
    z = re.findall(r'(?=htt).*?(?<=htm)', y)
    e = str(z)
    f = len(e)
    f = int(f)
    h = f-2
    r = e[2:h]
    print(r)

Basically I reasoned that if if I find out the length of the string (which varies) than trim or print only the range I need it works. As I said I do not know if it is the correct method but it worked.